# MySQL/MariaDB DELETE query worked fine yesterday, affects 0 rows today... query unchanged

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xampp, mariadb

I'm working on a localhost XAMPP setup running MariaDB 10.3.16 and wrote the following query which deletes rows from multiple tables based on the first table's "ID" column. The problem is, **it worked fine yesterday, and won't affect anything at all today on identical test data**.

I've renamed my tables in this example, but everything else is the same. Assuming we're trying to delete multiple IDs 48, 49 and 50, which currently exist:

```
delete t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8 from table1 as t1
join table2 as t2 on t2.account_id = t1.id
join table3 as t3 on t3.account_id = t1.id
join table4 as t4 on t4.account_id = t1.id
join table5 as t5 on t5.account_id = t1.id
join table6 as t6 on t6.account_id = t1.id
join table7 as t7 on t7.account_id = t1.id
join table8 as t8 on t8.account_id = t1.id
where t1.id in (48,49,50);
```

I'm kinda pulling my hair out right now, because this query worked great multiple times yesterday as I was adding rows to test it on in my various tables. It worked every time. Today, I did some other work on a totally unrelated section of my project, and came back to using the DELETE endpoint of my API - only to discover this query simply will not delete anything any more. It goes through just fine, but it's now affecting 0 rows.

Copy & pasting the query directly into phpMyAdmin, where it also used to work, gives me the same result - 0 rows affected.

- Is there something wrong with my query? Would you write this differently?
- Is there any reason why the same query, in the same environment, working with the same test data, would work one day and not the next? A glitch maybe?

Comment: can you post also the relevant table data?

Comment: Temporarily try changing the `delete t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8` to a `select *`. If no rows are found, then that means that some of the tables are missing the id's specified in the where clause to complete the various joins.

Comment: Thanks Paul. T, I tried what you suggested, and indeed got a 0 result set on the select. I tried reducing my query to only look in tables that I know have the proper IDs in them, and everything worked :) However, I'd like my query to continue to delete properly, skipping over tables that don't contain the IDs... do you know how I can modify it to do that, while keeping the current structure and tables? AKA - I want the operation to complete in every table where the IDs exist, instead of requiring all tables to contain them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Paul T. for putting me on the right path!

The issue with my query was that *it only deleted anything if ALL of the tables contained the account_ids I was searching for*. If any of them had no data for the associated ids, the DB would just stop and not affect anything.

I searched around a little more and found that changing **JOIN** in my query to **LEFT JOIN** allows the operation to complete in all tables where the ids were found, skipping over the ones that didn't have them. Time to read up some more on SQL!

Comment: I was going to suggest the left join, but was not sure of the expected goal. At least you found the answer, which makes for a good learning experience! My suggestion is typically what I do to check what will be deleted, by running a select _first_ to see what is found before running the delete.